# How to get the final URL from a redirect in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, url, redirect

I need to get the final URL from a link that gets redirected. (e.g. if someone is using a URL shortener)

```
bit.ly/foobar ->redirect-> http://example.com
```

What the fastest way to do this in AS3?
Thanks you

Comment: @Marcela Yes, an AIR solution would work also for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using AIR, you can listen for an `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS` event:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http://bit.ly/1bdDlXc"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, urlLoader_httpResponseStatus);

function urlLoader_httpResponseStatus(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void 
{
        trace(e.redirected, e.responseURL);
}
```

The result of the above trace is `true http://www.google.com/`

This event gives you information about whether the URL was redirected and what the new URL is.